# UICollectionViewCell only shown when debug step by step

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I can't get my custom UICollectionViewCell to be shown when run without put a breakpoint in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` and debug step by step through it. After that my custom cells will be shown fine. Something wrong from xcode builder or my code?

p/s: I register my custom UICollectionViewCell by className like this: `clvDishes.registerClass(PosItemsCollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DishesCollectionViewCell")` and create cell's layout all in code(not using xib file)

Here is my code

```
class PosCollectionViewSource<T>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var items:[T] = []
    var identifier:String!
    override init() {
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier + "CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        switch(String(T)){
        case "PosItemsInfo":
            let itemsCell = cell  as! PosItemsCollectionViewCell
            let posItems = items as Any as! [PosItemsInfo]
            itemsCell.updateCell(posItems[indexPath.item])
            return itemsCell

        default : break
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class PosItemsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

        private var _lblItemName:UILabel!
        private var _lblItemPrice:UILabel!
        private var _vOverlayInfo:UIView!
        private var _imvPictureContainer:UIImageView!
        private var _vSeparate:UIView!
        private var _imvWarning:UIImageView!
        private var _imvSeason:UIImageView!
        private var _lblRemaining:UILabel!


        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            let uiFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 17) as UIFont?

            _lblItemName = UILabel()
            _lblItemName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            _lblItemName.font = uiFont

            _lblItemPrice = UILabel()
            _lblItemPrice.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            _lblItemPrice.font = uiFont

            _vSeparate = UIView()
            _vSeparate.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "FFFFFF", a: 0.5)

            _vOverlayInfo = UIView()
            _vOverlayInfo.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#000000", a:0.21)

            _imvPictureContainer = UIImageView()
            _imvPictureContainer.image = UIImage(named: "pos_DefaultDishIcon")

            _vOverlayInfo.addSubview(_lblItemName)
            _vOverlayInfo.addSubview(_lblItemPrice)
            _vOverlayInfo.addSubview(_vSeparate)

            _lblRemaining = UILabel()
            _lblRemaining.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "E86E2B")
            _lblRemaining.SetBorder("E86E2B", radius: 0)
            _lblRemaining.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            _lblRemaining.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 20)
            _lblRemaining.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

            _imvSeason = UIImageView()
            _imvSeason.image = UIImage(named: "pos_SeasonIcon")

            _imvWarning = UIImageView()


            contentView.addSubview(_imvPictureContainer)
            contentView.addSubview(_vOverlayInfo)
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        func updateCell(item:PosItemsInfo){
            _lblItemName.text = item.itemName
            _lblItemPrice.text =  item.itemPrice?.toString("%.2f")
            _lblRemaining.text = item.itemQtyRemaining?.toString()

            if item.itemQtyStatus == PosItemQtyStatus.SoldOut{
                contentView.addSubview(_imvWarning)
                _imvWarning.image = UIImage(named: "pos_SoldOut")
            }
            else if item.itemQtyStatus == PosItemQtyStatus.LowInStock{
                contentView.addSubview(_imvWarning)
                contentView.addSubview(_lblRemaining)
                _imvWarning.image = UIImage(named: "pos_LowStock")
                _lblRemaining.text = item.itemQtyRemaining?.toString()
            }

            if item.itemIsSeason == true {
                contentView.addSubview(_imvSeason)
            }


        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            _vOverlayInfo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: contentView.frame.height - 60, width: 205, height: 60)
            _imvPictureContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 205, height: 160)
            _lblItemName.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width - 20, height: _vOverlayInfo.frame.height/2 )
            _lblItemPrice.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: _lblItemName.frame.height, width: contentView.frame.width - 20, height: _vOverlayInfo.frame.height/2 )
            _vSeparate.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: _lblItemName.frame.height, width: contentView.frame.width - 16, height: 1 )
            _lblRemaining.frame = CGRect(x: (contentView.frame.width - 50)/2, y: 40, width: 50, height: 50)
            _imvWarning.frame = CGRect(x: 125, y: 0, width: 81, height: 74)
        }

        override func didMoveToSuperview() {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        }
```

---

```
    class PosDishesVCtrl: PosBaseController {

    @IBOutlet weak var clvDishes: UICollectionView!

    private var _clvDataSource:PosCollectionViewSource<PosItemsInfo>!
    private var _items:[PosItemsInfo]!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modifiedOrUpdateUI()
        renderDishes()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func modifiedOrUpdateUI(){
        clvDishes.setCollectionViewLayout(LayoutGridType, animated: false)
        clvDishes.registerClass(PosItemsCollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DishesCollectionViewCell")
        clvDishes.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "979797", a: 1)
        clvDishes.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        clvDishes.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        clvDishes.pagingEnabled = false
        clvDishes.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        clvDishes.contentSize = CGSize(width: clvDishes.frame.width, height: clvDishes.frame.height)
        clvDishes.scrollsToTop = false
    }

    func renderDishes(){
        if(_clvDataSource == nil){
            _clvDataSource = PosCollectionViewSource<PosItemsInfo>()
            _clvDataSource.identifier = "Dishes"
            _items = [PosItemsInfo]()
        }

        for var i = 0; i < 12; i++ {
            let item = PosItemsInfo()
            item.itemName = "Dish " + String(i)
            item.itemPrice = Double(i)
            item.itemQtyRemaining = 4
            if(i%2 == 0){
                item.itemIsSeason = true
                item.itemQtyStatus = PosItemQtyStatus.LowInStock
            }
            else {
                item.itemQtyStatus = PosItemQtyStatus.SoldOut
            }
            _items.append(item)
        }

        clvDishes.setCollectionViewLayout(LayoutGridType, animated: false)
        _clvDataSource.items = _items
        clvDishes.dataSource = _clvDataSource

        clvDishes.delegate = PosCollectionViewDelegate(ctr: self)
        clvDishes.reloadData()
        clvDishes.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

}
```

Any idea would be appreciate!

Comment: please check my updated! I code every class in a single file also

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DataSource method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)
    -> Int
{
    return items.count
}
```

is always returning zero.  Your row indices correspond to the number of items (cells) you'll return here.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the code you've provided, it isn't apparent that you ever add any items to the `PosCollectionViewSource.items` array, so I expect `items.count` to return zero.  If it does not, then you must be adding items to the array somewhere else (in source code you haven't posted).

Looking at your code, I notice that the way you're setting up your custom cell class and using it is a bit complicated (possibly wrong) and could be better.

Assuming that you *are* adding elements to the `items` array somewhere, let's try a different approach:

Here's a pattern I use for cell types with `reuseIdentifier`s (`UITableViewCell`, `UICollectionViewCell`, etc.):

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // This will do the right thing for CustomCell and its subclasses
    class var reuseIdentifier: String { return "\(self)" }
}
```

Now, when you register the custom class, do it like this:

```
collectionView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, CustomCell.reuseIdentifier)
```

and fetch one like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CustomCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! CustomCell

    // setup the cell as necessary:
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Not sure yet! Because if I put a breakpoint at "let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier + "CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)" and step over immediatly it works fine

Comment: also I've just debug on this function it returns 12

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on **iOS 14** (simulator & actual devices). Cells would only be displayed if I stopped running the app with a debug breakpoint before returning each cell.

A solution that worked for me was to call `cell.setNeedsLayout()` before returning the cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueCellOfType(MyCell.self, for: indexPath)
    // Make the call below:
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    return cell
}
```